# cordova android build error for push notification

Tags: android, cordova

I am working on an android project that makes use of push notifications. I have installed the plugin with the command cordova plugin add https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-push --variable SENDER_ID=xxxxxx
I get the following response after I have run: cordova build android

Error response:
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred evaluating project ':app'.

> Failed to apply plugin [class 'com.google.gms.googleservices.GoogleServicesPlugin']
>   Cannot add extension with name 'googleServices', as there is an extension already registered with that name.